# Creating a simple shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I am trying to learn the shared library concepts on linux using GCC. So I have created a simple library.

*library.c*

```
int foo(void)  {
    return 10;
}
```

This is compiled using,

```
cc -fPIC -g -c library.c
cc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libmytest.so.1 -o libmytest.so.1.0.1 library.o -lc
```

It created the file `libmytest.so.1.0.1` in the current directory. Now I am writing a client to consume this library in the same directory.

*client.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo(void);

int main()
{
    int a = foo();
    printf("a is %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

compiling using,

```
cc client.c -o client -lmytest
```

but this exits with the message

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmytest
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help me to find out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a `-L` option which is used to add a directory to the list of directories that are searched for the `-l` option:

```
cc client.c -L. -o client -lmytest
```

Assuming the `.so` is present in the same directory as `client.c`. If not add suitable path.

The linker on seeing `-lmytest` looks for `libmytest.so` but you have a version number appended to it so it does not work. Way to fix this is to create a symlink named `libmytest.so` pointing to `libmytest.so.1.0.1`

```
ln -s libmytest.so.1.0.1 libmytest.so
```

Alternatively you can use the complete library name on the compile/link line as:

```
cc client.c ./libmytest.so.1.0.1 -o client
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. still the same error. I even tried with specifying the full path, but not worked.

Comment: I got it working by providing the library name directly and not through -l.

Comment: May I know why you are using `-soname,libmytest.so.1`?

Comment: @codaddict: my guess is cargo-cult coding.

Comment: @codaddict: I found one of the tutorials says "-soname,libmytest.so.1". What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the -Ldir option.

From the GCC manpage:

> ```
> -Ldir  Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l.
> ```

You'll also need to specify where the shared library is located if you try to run the executable, otherwise the library won't be found.  This can be done with:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./client`

Edit:

> Thanks but no luck. still the same
>   error. I even tried with specifying
>   the full path, but not worked.

I think the linker needs the library to have a .so extension.  Try `ln -s libmytest.so.1.0.1 libmytest.so` and see if it links.

Comment: As an alternative to setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` every time you run the executable, you can set `LD_RUN_PATH` when you link it, which will embed the additional search path for the shared library into the executable.

Answer (score 1):

The linker normally searches only the system paths for libraries. Pass `-L` to `gcc` in order to specify additional paths to search.